# Showing data Table dynamically in TableLayout from exist Table in sqlite database

Tags: android, mysql, sql, scrollview, android-tablelayout

I am new in database and tableLayout. I want to show my exist dataTable to the user in an activity. But I don't know how I can I do it. I tried little bit. But couldn't do that yet. But my row is being column and column is being row. What should my code be! And table layout should be scroll able horizontally. Advance thanks for your answer.

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.shubho.speedypaper17.SavedDataActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/table"/>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Java Code:

```
public class SavedDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{
String tableName;
String[] columnNames;
String[] array = null;
SQLiteDatabase db;
TextView textView;
ArrayList<String> ar =null;
Cursor c;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_data);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    tableName = intent.getExtras().getString("abc");

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText("" + tableName + "");

    columnNames = c.getColumnNames();

    addHeaders();
    addData();
}

private TextView getTextView(int id, String title, int color, int typeface, 
int bgColor) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setId(id);
    tv.setText(title.toUpperCase());
    tv.setTextColor(color);
    tv.setPadding(40, 40, 40, 40);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, typeface);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
    tv.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    return tv;
}

@NonNull
private LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(2, 0, 0, 2);
    return params;
}

@NonNull
private TableLayout.LayoutParams getTblLayoutParams() {
    return new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
//This is my header of the table column.
public void addHeaders() {
    TableLayout tl = findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
    for(int i =0; i<columnNames.length; i++){
        tr.addView(getTextView(0, ""+columnNames[i]+"", Color.WHITE, 
Typeface.BOLD, Color.BLUE));
    }
    tl.addView(tr, getTblLayoutParams());
}

/**
 * This function add the data to the table
 **/
public void addData() {


    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
        array = null;
        ar = null;
        ar = new ArrayList();
        c.moveToFirst();
        do{
            ar.add(c.getString(i));

        }while (c.moveToNext());
        array = new String[ar.size()];
        array = ar.toArray(array);
        TableLayout tl = findViewById(R.id.table);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

            tr.addView(getTextView(j + 1, array[j], Color.WHITE, 
Typeface.NORMAL, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)));

        }
        tl.addView(tr, getTblLayoutParams());
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    TextView tv = findViewById(id);
    if (null != tv) {
        Log.i("onClick", "Clicked on row :: " + id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on row :: " + id + ", Text :: " + 
tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

The screenshot of my done work is:

[image]

Comment: Transpose your data before showing it.

Comment: Sir, I didn't get you. at necessary place, help me changing the code. Please...

Comment: Can you please share your table structure and desired output?

Comment: Sir, see the Attached screen sort. There's row is being column and column is being row.